# How can I save API data directly into the database or local storage automatically using a specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, local-storage

I came up with this question on Stack Overflow because I could not solve a small problem that I had been dealing with for a long time.

One problem I do not understand is:

- I want a function that automatically sets the data from the API and automatically saves it directly to Local Storage or Database by specific local time zone using with pure JavaScript.
- I want the data to be automatically saved to LocalStorage or Database at **12:01 local time and 4:30 pm** then display it to HTML DOM.
- **I want a API get the update data in every seconds.**

Please take a look at some of the codes I wrote myself.

```
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* -------------------------- Retrieve API ------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    // Fetch Meow Data Main();
    const pjk_Meow = async () => {
        const base = 'aHR0cHM6Ly90d29';
        const cors = atob('aHR0cHM6Ly9jb3JzLmNo');
        const pjk_meow = atob(base);

        try {
            const res = await fetch(cors + pjk_meow);
            const data = await res.json();

            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            return error.message;
        }
    };

    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* -------------------------- Schedule and Save to Local Storage ------------------------- */
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    // // 12:00 PM Request Data
    const pjk_Meow_4 = async () => {
        const base = 'aHR0cHM6Ly90d29';
        const cors = atob('aHR0cHM6Ly9jb3JzLmNoY');
        const pjk_meow = atob(base);

        // Set default time what I want it to.
        let d_time = '12:03:12 PM';
        let d_time_2 = '12:10:12 PM';
        let current_time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();


        try {
            if (current_time === d_time || current_time <= 13) {
                try {
                    const res = await fetch(cors + pjk_meow);
                    const data = await res.json();

                    // Working with LS
                    let data_serialized = JSON.stringify(data);
                    localStorage.setItem('afternoon', data_serialized);

                    return data_serialized;
                } catch (error) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    pjk_Meow_4();

    // 12:00 PM Callback and output to html
    const twelve_pm = () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            try {
                let third_Data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('afternoon'));

                const setThird = document.getElementById('setThird');
                const valueThird = document.getElementById('valueThird');
                const resultThird = document.getElementById('resultThird');

                // If there is no any data in LS, this condition will run
                if (localStorage.length <= 0 || localStorage === undefined) {
                    setThird.innerText = '------';
                    valueThird.innerText = '-------';
                    resultThird.innerText = '--';
                }

                // Destructuring 12:00 PM Result
                const { set, val, result } = third_Data;

                // Check time and get data
                setThird.innerText = set;
                valueThird.innerText = val;
                resultThird.innerText = result;
            } catch (error) {
                return false;
            }
        }, 3000);
    };
    twelve_pm();

    // // 4:30 PM Request Data
    const pjk_Meow_3 = async () => {
        const base = 'aHR0cHM6Ly90d29kLml0';
        const cors = atob('aHR0cHM6Ly9jb3J');
        const pjk_meow = atob(base);

        // Set default time what I want it to.
        let d_time_1 = '04:35:00 PM';
        let d_time_2 = '16:35:00 PM';
        let current_time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

        // let current_time = new Date().getHours();
        try {
            if (current_time === d_time_1 || current_time >= d_time_2) {
                try {
                    const res = await fetch(cors + pjk_meow);
                    const data = await res.json();

                    // Working with LS
                    let data_serialized = JSON.stringify(data);
                    localStorage.setItem('evening', data_serialized);

                    return data_serialized;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    pjk_Meow_3();

    // 4:30 PM Callback and output to html
    const four_pm = () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            try {
                let second_Data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('evening'));

                const setSec = document.getElementById('setSec');
                const valueSec = document.getElementById('valueSec');
                const resultSec = document.getElementById('resultSec');

                // If there is no any data in LS, this condition will run
                if (localStorage.length <= 0 || localStorage === undefined) {
                    setSec.innerText = '------';
                    valueSec.innerText = '-------';
                    resultSec.innerText = '--';
                }

                // Destructuring 12:00 PM Result
                const { set, val, result } = second_Data;

                // Check time and get data
                setSec.innerText = set;
                valueSec.innerText = val;
                resultSec.innerText = result;
            } catch (error) {
                return false;
            }
        }, 3000);
    };
    four_pm();
```

**OR**

Please take a look at some of the codes I wrote updated.

```
// Set the default time what I want to save to the localStorage
        let d = new Date();
        let h = d.getHours();
        let m = d.getMinutes();
        let compile = `${h}:${m}`;

        try {
            if (compile === '4:30' || compile >= '16:30') {
                try {
                    const res = await fetch(cors + pjk_meow);
                    const data = await res.json();

                    // Working with LS
                    let data_serialized = JSON.stringify(data);
                    localStorage.setItem('evening', data_serialized);

                    return data_serialized;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: The value returned by *new Date().toLocaleTimeString()* is implementation dependent, so comparing it to a fixed string is bound to fail always for some (most?) users. For me it produces "11:21:33".  Also, it's a string so `current_time <= 13` will almost certainly be false, always.

Comment: Yes, Do you have an any idea to references provided with some example codes by using javascript for the specific time function?

Comment: I appreciate it yor leaving comment, by the way.

Comment: Using relational operators for string comparisons is fraught (you are comparing substrings or code units, not numbers), far better to keep hrs and mins as numbers and compare to numbers. Convert to say minutes so `m += h * 60` then `if (m == 270 || m >= 990)`.